# django haystack not returning results according to expectations

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, django-haystack, django-1.4

I have configured Django haystack with Elasticsearch Search Engine using `QueuedSignalProcessor` with `redis` Queue backend. Everything working except now I have some issue. I have two objects in db whose title is `code fixes` and `code fixess` (with extra `s` at end). I need to perform partial search. When I search for `code fix` it return the object with title `code fixes` but it is not returning object with title `code fixess`:

```
my_model = SearchQuerySet().models(MyModel)
objects = my_model.filter(content__contains=q) # q = "code fix"
```

indexes file:

```
from haystack import indexes
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr="title")
```

index template:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.description }}
```

P.S the index is updated. As if I search for `fixess` it shows the second object with title `code fixess` but not first in this case. If I search for just `code` it returns both.

What would be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because Haystack is configured to use the [Snowball analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-analyzer.html)

This looks for known (English) word endings, such as the `es` in `fixes` and storing the *stem* word (`fix`) in the index instead of the exact word, allowing a kind of fuzzy matching.

I presume the Snowball analyzer does not recognise the `ess` from `fixess` as an ending, hence it doesn't prune the word down to a stem.

ElasticSearch actually provides many other analyzers, and also allows you define a custom analyzer from the building blocks of tokenizers + filters. Mis-spellings in the source data is maybe a tricky one to deal with though... you may need to try a phonetic ('sounds like') approach:
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic

Finally, try this project which makes it easier to customise the ElasticSearch config that Haystack uses:
https://github.com/bennylope/elasticstack